# How to create an equation with 3 variables, given two points in 3-dimensions?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I have two points: (20.33, 16.1, 0.0150) & (20.48, 19, 0.0123),
and I would like an equation of the line that connects these two points, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Is there a form of Y = MX + B, but in 3-dimensions? Iv'e already got the parametric equations and vector equations, but that doesn't seem to get me what I'm looking for. I would like to be able to enter in two values, say Y & Z, and then find out what X is. The vector equation is:

(x-0.15)/20.33 = (y-2.9)/16.1 = (z+0.0027)/0.0150

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is impossible or not...
Instead of just plugging in X, and calculation Y and Z - I would like to plug both X and Y, and calculate Z.

Thanks so much for any feedback!

- Cole

Comment: There is no $y=mx+b$ for a line in three dimensions. You will have to go by parametric form or as you describe, a vector equation

Comment: The equation you wrote is exactly what you want. For a point on a line, one of the three coordinates ($x$, $y$ or $z$) is sufficient to determine where it is.

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes more sense I suppose. Perhaps what I'm really looking for is a plane to describe  my data rather than a line.

Comment: Maybe, but for a plane in the three dim world, you need three points, not two. And these three points can't be collinear (why?)

Comment: Well I would actually have three points, I was only using two for simplification. The points above all correspond to (extraction, ratio, total dissolved solids), these are referring to brewing coffee actually - just to put things into perspective. I would like to specify both extraction and ratio, and then find out the corresponding total dissolved solids accordingly. Now that I think of it though, I couldn't imagine a line being able to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points $P$ and $Q$, an equation for the line connecting them is $P+(1-t)Q$, where $t$ is the parametric variable for the line.

Comment: Thanks for that, although I don't quite understand what t is. Or at least how that would apply to my situation. Also if there is no equality, wouldn't that not be an equation?

Comment: To get an equation, you could write out the three coordinates: $x=20.33+(1-t)20.48$, $y=16.1+(1-t)19$, and lastly $z=0.0150+(1-t)0.0123$.